# C++11 auto, std::function and ambiguous call to overloaded function

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-construction, overloading, std

I'm wondering if anyone knows why the following sample doesn't compile giving an ambiguous call to overload function error. If I replace the auto with a strongly typed functor signature, it then is able to properly distinguish between the two method overloads.

I noticed the same issue doesn't occur when not using std::function as my overload arguments. If my overloads take just a simple float and int, the compiler can properly distinguish between the two overloads even when using the auto keyword to define my input arguments. I'm compiling this in VisualStudio 2012. Could this just be an bug in the VS compiler? I don't have access to a machine with GCC or Clang on it right now, but does anyone know if this would compile there?

**Compile Error: ambiguous call to overload function**

```
class AmbiguousOverload
{
public:
    static void OverloadedMethod(std::function<int()>) {}
    static void OverloadedMethod(std::function<float()>) {}
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    auto func1 = []() -> float {
        return 0.5f;
    };

    auto func2 = []() -> int {
        return 12;
    };

    AmbiguousOverload::OverloadedMethod(func1);
    AmbiguousOverload::OverloadedMethod(func2);

    return 0;
}
```

**Compiles**

```
class AmbiguousOverload
{
public:
    static void OverloadedMethod(std::function<int()>) {}
    static void OverloadedMethod(std::function<float()>) {}
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::function<float()> func1 = []() -> float {
        return 0.5f;
    };

    std::function<int()> func2 = []() -> int {
        return 12;
    };

    AmbiguousOverload::OverloadedMethod(func1);
    AmbiguousOverload::OverloadedMethod(func2);

    return 0;
}
```

**Also Compiles**

```
class AmbiguousOverload
{
public:
    static void OverloadedMethod(int) {}
    static void OverloadedMethod(float) {}
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    auto v1 = 0.5f;
    auto v2 = 12;

    AmbiguousOverload::OverloadedMethod(v1);
    AmbiguousOverload::OverloadedMethod(v2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A lambda is no std::function

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`std::function` had a greedy `template` constructor that will attempt to construct it from anything at all you passed it<sup>1</sup>.  `std::function` is not very suitable for use in overload resolution.  It worked in one case because perfect matches are preferred to conversion, but as noted it is fragile.

Note that lambdas and `std::function` objects are unrelated types.  `std::function` knows how to wrap a lambda, but it can wrap any copyable invokable object.  Lambdas are auto-created anonymously named classes that are copyable and invokable.  `std::function` is a class designed to type-erase invocation.

Imagine if your overrides took `short` and `long`.  The `auto x = 2.0` and `short s = 2.0` would correspond to the `auto x = lambda` and `std::function<blah> f = lambda` cases.  When you pick the type explicitly you cause a type conversion, and the types you picked explicitly had no ambiguity.  But when you did `auto` it took the real type -- and the real type was ambiguous.

SFINAE or tag dispatching using `std::result_of` would let you handle these overrides manually.

In [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) this changed a bit.  Now the constructor only tries to swallow *compatible* arguments.  But a function returning `int` and one returning `float` are both compatible with each other, so it won't help your specific case.

---

<sup>1</sup> To a certain extent this is a flaw in `std::function`.  Its "universal" constructor should really only participate in overload resolution when the type passed in is both copyable **and** `std::result_of_t< X( Args... ) >` can be converted to the result type of the `std::function`.  I suspect post-concepts this will be added to the standard, as post-concepts this is really easy to both write and express (and very little conforming code will be broken by it).  However, in this particular case, this would not actually help, as `int` and `float` can be converted into each other, and there are no ways to say "this constructor will work, but really it isn't a preferred option".

Comment: It's only a very limited flaw, I suppose, since it is already possible to express what you want. It's just not as completely easy as it might be.

Comment: @kerreksb That is a low standard you hold `std` to.  Similar flaws exist in `vector::operator<` etc: `std` has lots of methods that are easy to check if they should exist, but do not.  I suspect a wholesale slaighter of them in C++1z or 2x.

Comment: I think that's debatable. There are situations where you don't want overloads to exist in the first place, but in other situations, you'd rather have a direct error message that "type X doesn't have an operator-`<`", rather than some obscure error. Imagine you change some container from `vector<X>` to `vector<Y>` and forgot to define the operator. Suddenly you'd get an error unrelated to the change from `X` to `Y`.

Comment: @kerreksb you would be told no `<` found for `std::vector<Y>`.  Candidate blah failed because `Y` failed the `<` test.  Error messages from concept failure rocks.

Comment: To a certain extent, for a staggering value of "certain"

Comment: @glenn Yes, "this is a really annoying flaw" would be a better wording.  But I was feeling charitable when I wrote the above answer.