# How to make these std::function parameters unambiguous?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, lambda, std-function

The following function overloads are ambiguous when passing a lambda. I found out that `std::function` can be [constructed from most callable types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22543082/1079110), even if their signature does not match. So the compiler can't tell which function to use.

```
template <typename T> void each(std::function<void(T)> iterator);
template <typename T> void each(std::function<void(T, id)> iterator);
template <typename T> void each(std::function<void(T&)> iterator);
template <typename T> void each(std::function<void(T&, id)> iterator);
```

There are some similar questions out here, but none of them could solve my problem. How can I resolve the ambiguity without changing the usage? Morever, at the time I have to explicitly mention the template type. Is there a way around this?

Comment: It won't match a lambda, there's no way for compiler to deduce `T`.

Comment: @Jamboree When I remove the first three overloads, it compiles fine for  `manager.entity.each<type::window>([=](type::window &window, id entity) { /* ... */ });`

Comment: oh, ok, so you specify `T` explicitly. In c++14, `std::function` is sfinae friendly so it won't be constructible from those not callable.

Comment: @Jamboree Now I understand what you meant. If there is a way to get rid of explicitly mentioning `T` that would be great, too!

Comment: Can you add a minimum compilable example (e.g. the exact ambiguous calls)

Comment: @quantdev [Here it is](http://ideone.com/e4MYJZ). Edit: Oh, I noticed that this compiles fine even with all four overloads. Maybe this is a Visual Studio problem?

Comment: I use VS12, which has the name VS2013. By the way, I noticed that when [targeting the first overload](http://ideone.com/l8vw42), the third is used. Moreover, it would be great to get rid of explicitly mentioning the template type, so I added that part to the question.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to overload 1 & 3 or 2 & 4, just as we don't overload `f(T)` and `f(T&)`.

Comment: @danijar I'm surprised that you don't get a compiler error over the ambiguity between `void(T)` and `void(T&)`, you probably would if it wasn't a templated function.

Comment: @Jamboree So I just define the pass-by-value version and depending on the lambda I use, it may become pass-by-reference?

Comment: @danijar No, it won't become pass-by-reference automatically, but you can specify `each<T&>(...)` explicitly, as @sjdowling pointed out, `void(T)` & `void(T&)` would be an error if not templated.

Comment: Part of this is http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#2132

Comment: Actually, they will all use the T& overload.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One half of this is [LWG issue 2132](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#2132), removing `std::function`'s constructor from overload resolution unless the argument is actually callable for the argument types specified. This requires expression SFINAE support to implement, which VC++ doesn't have.

The other half of the issue is overload resolution:

```
#include<functional>
#include<iostream>
struct id {};
template <typename T> void each(std::function<void(T)> ){ std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
template <typename T> void each(std::function<void(T, id)> ){ std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
template <typename T> void each(std::function<void(T&)> ){ std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
template <typename T> void each(std::function<void(T&, id)> ){ std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
int main() {
    each<int>([](int, id){});
}
```

With a library that implements LWG2132, [this code prints](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/594b33e6880548ca), perhaps surprisingly:

```
void each(std::function<void(T&, id)>) [with T = int]
```

Why? First, it is possible to construct a `std::function<void(T&, id)>` from `[](int, id){}`. After all, the latter *can* be called with a lvalue of type `int` just fine.

Second, in

```
template <typename T> void each(std::function<void(T, id)>);
template <typename T> void each(std::function<void(T&, id)>);
```

The second is more specialized than the first by the partial ordering rules for function templates, so it's always chosen by overload resolution.

---

A possible solution is to extract the signature by manipulating the type of the lambda's `operator ()`:

```
template<class T>
struct mem_fn_type;
template<class R, class C, class... T>
struct mem_fn_type<R(C::*)(T...)> {
    using type = std::function<R(T...)>;
};
template<class R, class C, class... T>
struct mem_fn_type<R(C::*)(T...) const> {
    using type = std::function<R(T...)>;
};

// optional extra cv-qualifier and ref-qualifier combos omitted
// since they will never be used with lambdas    

// Detects if a class is a specialization of std::function
template<class T>
struct is_std_function_specialization : std::false_type {};

template<class T>
struct is_std_function_specialization<std::function<T>> : std::true_type{};

// Constrained to not accept cases where T is a specialization of std::function,
// to prevent infinite recursion when a lambda with the wrong signature is passed
template<class T>
typename std::enable_if<!is_std_function_specialization<T>::value>::type each(T func) {
    typename mem_fn_type<decltype(&T::operator())>::type f = func;
    each(f);
}
```

This won't work for generic lambdas (whose `operator()` is a template) or for arbitrary function objects (which may have arbitrarily many `operator()` overloads).

Comment: Isn't there a way around the first half of the problem, by using a signature like `template <typename T> void each(T iterator);` and converts to `std::function` internally?

Comment: Thanks. Could you add an usage example for the signatures I provided in the question, please? At the moment, my understanding isn't good enough to apply your solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understand it and could apply it.

Answer (score 1):

> Morever, at the time I have to explicitly mention the template type. Is there a way around this?

The canonical solution for this is to implement a generic dependency injection point (i.e. single overload) and allow client code to decide what it puts in there. I am unsure how to give an example that makes sense for the code you provided, because I cannot imagine what a function called `each` would do with a parameter called iterator (when that parameter is a functor that returns `void`).

A function similar to yours would be applied for the visitor pattern, so I will give you an example using that:

```
class collection {
    std::vector<int> data; // to be visited
public:
    void visit(std::function<void(int)> visitor) // single overload
    {
        std::for_each(std::begin(data), std::end(data), visitor);
    }
};

void complex_visitor(int element, double EXTRA, char* PARAMETERS, bool HERE);
```

Client code:

```
collection c;
char* data = get_some_data();
bool a = false;
c.visit( [&](int x) { complex_visitor(x, .81, data, a); } );
```

In this example, it is on the last line (i.e. in client code) that you decide *how* to plug in a non-matching visitor, not in the interface of the `collection` class.

Comment: Yes, I use the visitor pattern. Maybe I shouldn't have removed so much from the example. However, I have four (without distinction between value and reference two) templated overloads. That's the problem.

Comment: If the four overloads implement the same algorithm, I think you should have a single implementation; If they implement different algorithms, they do different things and should probably be named differently (thus avoiding the conflict completely). I cannot imagine a situation where the functions should be called the same but do completely different things (and in that case, I don't have a solution - at least not one that doesn't turn into an obscure maintenance nightmare in six months :( ).

Comment: As pointed out by some people, I can't overload just by talking a reference rather than a value. So I'm left with two overloads. The one that provides additional `id` parameter to the visitor differs in the way that it provides this, not more than that. Can I have a single implementation that supports both, lambdas with one parameter `T` and lambdas with two parameters `T, id`?