# Why is this call of overloaded function ambiguous?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, stl

Why is this constructor call ambiguous?

```
#include <functional>

class A {
    std::function<int(void)> f_;
    std::function<float(void)> g_;
public:
    A(std::function<int(void)> f) { f_ = f; }
    A(std::function<float(void)> g) { g_ = g; }
    ~A() {}
};

int main()
{
    A a([](){ return (int)1; });
    return 0;
}
```

Note the typecast.

Is there a way to tell the compiler which constructor overload to use?

Comment: But it works when i use another return type for the function template (e.g. a pointer type)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542780/c11-auto-stdfunction-and-ambiguous-call-to-overloaded-function

Comment: What are you trying to do? Perhaps starting from that would be better here. For instance, you can store both a `[]()->int` and `[]()->float` into a `function<boost::variant<int, float>()>`. Then after calling it, you can get the result by `boost::apply_visitor(a.f(), [](auto x) { ... })`

Answer (score 4):

Because what you are passing doesn't match the types so we enter into conversion sequences to find the overload to use.  Both versions of function can be implicitly created from a lambda object that returns int.  Thus the compiler can't decide which to choose to create; though it seems intuitively obvious the rules in C++ don't allow for it.

Edit:

Written off the cuff but I think this could do the trick:

```
template < typename Fun >
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<typename std::result_of<Fun()>::type, int>::value>::type f(Fun f) ...


template < typename Fun >
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<typename std::result_of<Fun()>::type, double>::value>::type f(Fun f) ...
```

etc...  Or you might use tag dispatching:

```
template < typename Fun, typename Tag >
struct caller;

template < typename T > tag {};

template < typename Fun >
struct caller<Fun, tag<int>> { static void call(Fun f) { f(); } };

// etc...

template < typename Fun >
void f(Fun fun) { caller<Fun, typename std::result_of<Fun()>>::call(fun); }
```

Comment: Is there another wrapper than function to deal with the lambda? One that has a less greedy template constructor?

Comment: You could create one using SFINAE perhaps.  To use on lambdas might require some metaprogramming skills beyond the basic, especially if you wanted to accept free functions and members as well.

Comment: I found out that it works with c style function pointers like `A(int (*f)(void));`.  Unfortunately it seems they are not compatible with the lambda's capture functionality. And my metaprogramming skills are not that advanced to understand this strange thing.

Answer (score 4):

It's a defect in the standard. See [DR 2132](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#2132):

> Consider the following:
>
> ```
> #include <functional>
>
> void f(std::function<void()>) {}
> void f(std::function<void(int)>) {}
>
> int main() {
>   f([]{});
>   f([](int){});
> }
> ```
>
> The calls to f in main are ambiguous. Apparently because the
>   conversion sequences to `std::function` from the lambdas are
>   identical. The standard specifies that the function object given to
>   `std::function` "shall be Callable (20.8.11.2) for argument types
>   `ArgTypes` and return type `R`." It doesn't say that if this is not
>   the case, the constructor isn't part of the overload set.

Try using a function pointer as an argument instead:

```
A(int f()) { f_ = f; }
A(float g()) { g_ = g; }
```

Comment: As i wrote in another comment, the function pointer arguments are not compatible with the lambda's capture functionality. For some reason, i get a `no matching function for call to ...` error when using function pointers and capture variables.

Comment: DR2132 is about removing the implicit conversion sequence from function objects not callable with the specified signature. In the OP's case, the lambda is callable for both signatures (`int()` and `float()`).

Answer (score 0):

```
template<class F,
  class R=std::result_of_t<F&()>,
  std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible<R,int>{}&&(!std::is_convertible<R,float>{}||std::is_integral<R>{}),int> =0
>
A(F&&f):A(std::function<int()>(std::forward<F>(f))){}
template<class F,
  class R=std::result_of_t<F&()>,
  std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible<R,float>{}&&(!std::is_convertible<R,int>{}||std::is_floating_point<R>{}, int> =0
>
A(F&&f):A(std::function<float()>(std::forward<F>(f))){}
A(std::function<int()> f) { f_ = f; }
A(std::function<float()> g) { g_ = g; }
```

Here we take ambiguous cases, and dispatch integral ones to the int overload, and non-floating to the float one.

Cases where it is convertible to both, yet neither floating point nor integral, remain ambiguous.  As they should.

The sfina clause can be tricky.  If it does not work, replace:

```
  std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible<R,float>{}&&(!std::is_convertible<R,int>{}||std::is_floating_point<R>{}, int> =0
```

With

```
  class=std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible<R,float>{}&&(!std::is_convertible<R,int>{}||std::is_floating_point<R>{}>
```

and similar for other ctor.  This *might* work in MSVC for example.

Full on tag dispatching may be required for msvc, due to lack of expression sfinae in 2015.