# Container with function member with variable number of arguments

Tags: c++, function, c++14

I'm trying to come up with a better way of representing the following:

```
using InsBase0 = std::tuple<std::string, std::function<void()>>;

static const std::array<InsBase0, 1> ins0_bases = {{
    {"NOP", 0x0},
}};

using InsBase1 = std::tuple<std::string, std::function<void(const std::string &)>>;

static const std::array<InsBase1, 7> ins1_bases = {{
    {"INC", 0x0},
    {"DEC", 0x0},
    {"AND", 0x0},
    {"OR",  0x0},
    {"XOR", 0x0},
    {"CP",  0x0},
    {"SUB", 0x0},
}};

using InsBase2 = std::tuple<std::string, std::function<void(const std::string &, const std::string&)>>;

static const std::array<InsBase2, 6> ins_bases = {{
    {"LD",  0x0},
    {"ADD", 0x0},
    {"ADC", 0x0},
    {"SBC", 0x0},
    {"JP",  0x0},
    {"JR",  0x0},
}};
```

(utterly contrived example, imagine functions in place of `0x0` and something more sane like a map instead of an array or a struct instead of the tuple)

The context is that this is an assembler, so I need to map instructions to functions.

In a perfect world, I'd like to be able to put all of the instructions into one array/container (with an additional `args` member to denote the number of args the function takes), but I'd be happy with not duplicating the definitions with `StructName0` as well

Comment: I would use enums instead of strings for the op names. Of course this will require to create convertion between the two when parsing, but the likelyhood of having a typo will decrease. Also your lookup could be faster.

Comment: A possibility, but I've got to convert from strings at some point anyway...

Comment: Could you post an example of one of the functions you are trying to call with this?

Comment: Not entirely sure how they're relevant? I've given you the type signatures above :) Most of them are one liners that are just doing a signal operations on some "register" members in a struct

Comment: You might be interested in `variant<std::function<void()>, std::function<void(const std::string &)>, std::function<void(const std::string &, const std::string&)>>`.

Comment: Quite a lengthy type sig! I was aware of such a thing, but I'm not sure I'm ready to go with c++17 just yet

Comment: @LordAro you can use boost implementation

Comment: Eh, boost is a large dependency that I'd rather avoid if at all possible

Comment: Would you be ok with std::exceptions being thrown?

Comment: i have no issue with exceptions :)

Answer (score 2):

Two bits of metaprogramming helpers:

```
template<std::size_t I>
using index=std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>;
template<class T> struct tag_t {constexpr tag_t(){};};
template<class T> tag_t<T> tag{};
template<std::size_t, class T>
using indexed_type = T;
```

Now we define an enum type for each of the argument counts:

```
enum class zero_op:std::size_t { NOP };
enum class one_op:std::size_t { INC };
enum class two_op:std::size_t { ADD };
```

Next, a mapping from the types to the argument count:

```
constexpr index<0> args( tag_t<zero_op> ) { return {}; }
constexpr index<1> args( tag_t<one_op> ) { return {}; }
constexpr index<2> args( tag_t<two_op> ) { return {}; }
```

This takes a template and a count and a type, and repeatedly passes the type to the template:

```
template<template<class...>class Z, class T, class Indexes>
struct repeat;
template<template<class...>class Z, class T, std::size_t I>
struct repeat<Z, T, index<I>>:
  repeat<Z, T, std::make_index_sequence<I>>
{};
template<template<class...>class Z, class T, std::size_t...Is>
struct repeat<Z, T, std::index_sequence<Is...>> {
  using type=Z<indexed_type<Is, T>...>;
};
template<template<class...>class Z, class T, std::size_t N>
using repeat_t = typename repeat<Z, T, index<N>>::type;
```

We use this to build our `std::function` signatures:

```
template<class...Args>
using void_call = std::function<void(Args...)>;

template<std::size_t N, class T>
using nary_operation = repeat_t< void_call, T, N >;
```

and `nary_operation< 3, std::string const& >` is `std::function<void(std::string const&,std::string const&,std::string const&)>`.

We use this to create a compile time polymorphic table:

```
template<class...Es>
struct table {
  template<class E>
  using operation = nary_operation<args(tag<E>), std::string const&>;
  template<class E>
  using subtable = std::map< E, operation<E> >;
  std::tuple< subtable<Es>... > tables;

  template<class E>
  operation<E> const& operator[]( E e ) {
    return std::get< subtable<E> >( tables )[e];
  }
};
```

or something like that.

If you have an intance of `table<zero_op, one_op, two_op> bob`, you can do

```
bob[ zero_op::NOP ]();
```

or

```
bob[ zero_op::INC ]("foo");
```

or

```
bob[ zero_op::ADD ]("foo", "bar");
```

The type of the enum in `[]` changes the type of the function object returned.

The above probably has typos.

But, the end result is type-safe.

Comment: I still need to get the string representation of the op ("NOP") into enum form somehow - thoughts on doing that (or rolling it into this) ?

Comment: @LordAro Map from string to variant of the enum types, use type-safe visitation to then parse the arguments.  Or make it a map from the string directly to a varant of `std::function`s; the type of this last one can be generated by my `nary_operation` and some additional metaprogramming.

Comment: I don't really have variant, because no C++17 or boost, could you possibly show an example of the latter option? (or something else)

Comment: @LordAro Both solutions in the previous comment involve variant.  If you want type safety with types that vary over a range based on runtime input, that says "use variant".  If you don't want type safety on argument types, pass vectors instead of individual arguments.  Those are your choices.  You can write your own variant if you don't have C++17 or boost.

Comment: Hmm. Seems that the latest stable versions of libc++ or libstdc++ don't have variant yet anyway, regardless of C++17 or not. Ideas on a quick-and-dirty variant solution for the meantime?

Comment: @lord ask that in a bew question?  "I do not have C++17 and cannot use boost; I want a variant.  What should I do?"  Or try to write one.  There may be source...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having a `std::string` argument for your functions, you could use a `std::vector<std::string>`, so you could store multiple arguments.

That would relate to something like :

```
using function_t = std::function<void(const std::vector<std::string>&)>;
static const std::unordered_map<std::string, function_t> instructions =
{
  {"INC", somefunc},
  ...
};
```

And then to call the proper instruction :

```
std::vector<std::string> arguments = { "zob", "zeb" };
auto result = instructions["INC"](arguments);
```

---

Edit :

Here's the rest of how I would do it, to prove you it's not that long :

```
/**
 * Your instruction type. Contains its name,
 * the function to call, and the number of args required
 */
struct Instruction {
    using function_t = std::function<void(std::vector<std::string>)>;
    std::string name;
    function_t function;
    std::size_t numargs;

    Instruction(const std::string& name = "undefined", const function_t& function = function_t(), std::size_t numargs = 0)
        : name(name)
        , function(function)
        , numargs(numargs) {}
}

/**
 * Your instruction set. It contains the instructions you want to register in.
 * You can call the instructions safely through this
 */
struct InstructionSet {
    std::unordered_map<std::string, Instruction> instructions;

    void callInstruction(const std::string& inst_name, const std::vector<std::string>& arguments) {
        if (!instructions.count(inst_name))
            return; // no instruction named "inst_name", return or throw something relevant

        auto instruction = instructions[inst_name];
        if (instruction.numargs != arguments.size())
            return; // too many / not enough parameters, return or throw something relevant

        instruction.function(arguments);
    }

    void registerInstruction(const Instruction& instruction) {
        instructions[instruction.name] = instruction;
    }
};

int main() {
    InstructionSet instruction_set;
    instruction_set.registerInstruction(Instruction(
        "INC",
        [](const std::vector<std::string>& arguments) {
            bake_cookies_plz(arguments);
        },
        2)
    );

    instruction_set.callInstruction("INC", { "1", "2" });

    return 0;
}
```

- Note 1 : in this example, the InstructionSet is responsible for checking the number of arguments passed, but the functions could do it themselves. I would do that if there was a possibility of variable arguments count
- Note 2 : the registering part is not quite elegant with lambdas, but it's quick to write
- Note 3 : if you want more type safety for your arguments, go check max66 answer to get an idea of how to master templates in this situation

Comment: Possible. The issue with this is that there's no nice way to say that the function has been passed the wrong number of arguments

Comment: Okay, so you could make a structure that would contain both the `function_t` and a number of arguments.
The set of instructions would be itself enclosed in a class, containing some method `callInstruction(arguments)` that would check if `instructions[name].argcount == arguments.size()`

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't figure out a way to store all operations in one structure and still have compile time checks. Yet it is possible to check the number of passed values at runtime.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

class operation
{
    using op0_funcptr = void(*)();
    using op1_funcptr = void(*)(const std::string&);
    using op2_funcptr = void(*)(const std::string&, const std::string&);

    using op0_func = std::function<void()>;
    using op1_func = std::function<void(const std::string&)>;
    using op2_func = std::function<void(const std::string&, const std::string&)>;

    std::tuple<
        op0_func,
        op1_func,
        op2_func> m_functions;

public:
    operation() :m_functions(op0_func(), op1_func(), op2_func()) {}
    operation(const op0_func& op) :m_functions(op, op1_func(), op2_func()) {}
    operation(const op0_funcptr& op) :m_functions(op, op1_func(), op2_func()) {}
    operation(const op1_func& op) :m_functions(op0_func(), op, op2_func()) {}
    operation(const op1_funcptr& op) :m_functions(op0_func(), op, op2_func()) {}
    operation(const op2_func& op) :m_functions(op0_func(), op1_func(), op) {}
    operation(const op2_funcptr& op) :m_functions(op0_func(), op1_func(), op) {}

    operation(const operation& other) = default;
    operation(operation&& other) = default;

    void operator()() { std::get<op0_func>(m_functions)(); }
    void operator()(const std::string& p1) { std::get<op1_func>(m_functions)(p1); }
    void operator()(const std::string& p1, const std::string& p2) { std::get<op2_func>(m_functions)(p1, p2); }
};


void nop()
{
    std::cout << "NOP" << std::endl;
}

void inc(const std::string& p1)
{
    std::cout << "INC(" << p1 << ")" << std::endl;
}

void add(const std::string& p1, const std::string& p2)
{
    std::cout << "ADD(" << p1 << ", " << p2 << ")" << std::endl;
}


std::unordered_map<std::string, operation> operations{ {
    { "NOP", nop },
    { "INC", inc },
    { "ADD", add }
} };

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    operations["NOP"]();
    operations["INC"]("R1");
    operations["ADD"]("R2", "R3");
    operations["ADD"]("R2"); //Throws std::bad_function_call
}
```

It's by far not the best solution, but it works.

If you want to make the access faster you can also try to change the lower part to something like this:

```
enum class OP : size_t
{
    NOP,
    INC,
    ADD,
    NUM_OPS
};

std::array<operation, (size_t)OP::NUM_OPS> operations{ nop ,inc, add };

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    operations[(size_t)OP::NOP]();
    operations[(size_t)OP::INC]("R1");
    operations[(size_t)OP::ADD]("R2", "R3");
    //operations[(size_t)OP::ADD]("R2"); //Throws std::bad_function_call
}
```

Comment: I'm currently edging towards this, just because it's the "cleaner" solution (purely IMO) as it doesn't have the magic metaprogramming i don't properly understand :) I'll accept assuming I can make it work with my code

Comment: I'm struggling to get the operations map to work - `error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::unordered_map<std::string, operation>' ` is there something I'm missing? ("constructor not viable: requires x arguments, but 1 was provided")

Comment: @LordAro Do you have a default constructor?

Comment: @LordAro Which compiler are you using? And which flags? Can you post the code in question and some more error output? I would recommend to use pastebin to keep the question itself clean.

Comment: Ah, i believe the issue was that i used a lambda `auto unimp = [](){ std::cerr << "Unimplemented!\n"; };` instead of a function. Why does that matter?

Comment: @LordAro I have to admit I didn't test lambdas. Looks like even `operation x(nop);` does not compile because of "ambigious call". I am pretty sure it's because of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542780/c11-auto-stdfunction-and-ambiguous-call-to-overloaded-function)

Comment: @LordAro I can confirm that it doesn't work with lambdas directly because of the greediness of the `std::function<>` constructor. If you keep only one constructor accepting an `std::function<>` it can be used with lambdas.

Comment: I'm having real trouble getting the unordered_map to compile - thoughts? http://hastebin.com/eyafaxeyew.coffeescript

Comment: @LordAro Can you show me the complete initialization and at least one of the "functions" you are using to initialize the `operation`?

Comment: http://hastebin.com/wibeveqiyi.cpp here y'go. I added an additional parameter to all functions. Ideally all the functions would be methods on the class instead, but i couldn't work out how to make that work either

Comment: @LordAro This doesn't use `std::function` but it works with member functions and should be more light weight in your case. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/27e6e7782ec284ae

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the use of single `std::map` where the key is the name of the function (`NOP`, `AND`, `ADD`, etc.).

Using inheritance, a trivial base class, a `std::function` wrapper...

Not really elegant, I suppose, but...

```
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>


struct funBase
 {
   // defined only to permit the dynamic_cast
   virtual void unused () const {};
 };

template <typename R, typename ... Args>
struct funWrap : public funBase
 {
   std::function<R(Args...)> f;

   funWrap (R(*f0)(Args...)) : f { f0 }
    { }
 };

template <typename R, typename ... Args>
std::unique_ptr<funBase> makeUFB (R(*f)(Args...))
 { return std::unique_ptr<funBase>(new funWrap<R, Args...>(f)); }

template <typename F, typename T, bool = std::is_convertible<F, T>::value>
struct getConv;

template <typename F, typename T>
struct getConv<F, T, true>
 { using type = T; };

template <typename F, typename T>
struct getConv<F, T, false>
 {  };

template <typename ... Args>
void callF (std::unique_ptr<funBase> const & fb, Args ... args)
 {
   using  derType = funWrap<void,
             typename getConv<Args, std::string>::type const & ...>;

   derType *  pdt { dynamic_cast<derType *>(fb.get()) };

   if ( nullptr == pdt )
      std::cout << "call(): error in conversion" << std::endl;
   else
      pdt->f(args...);
 }

void fNop ()
 { std::cout << "NOP!" << std::endl; }

void fAnd (std::string const & s)
 { std::cout << "AND! [" << s << ']' << std::endl; }

void fAdd (std::string const & s1, std::string const & s2)
 { std::cout << "ADD! [" << s1 << "] [" << s2 << ']' << std::endl; }

int main()
 {
   std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<funBase>> fm;

   fm.emplace("NOP", makeUFB(fNop));
   fm.emplace("AND", makeUFB(fAnd));
   fm.emplace("ADD", makeUFB(fAdd));

   callF(fm["NOP"]);                  // print NOP!
   callF(fm["AND"], "arg");           // print AND! [arg]
   callF(fm["ADD"], "arg1", "arg2");  // print ADD! [arg1] [arg2]
   callF(fm["ADD"], "arg1");          // print call(): error in conversion
   //callF(fm["ADD"], "arg1", 12);      // compilation error 

   return 0;
 }
```

P.s.: works with C++11 too.

Comment: How effective would rolling `makeUFB` and `callF` into constructors and operators be? seems like it would be cleaner than the extra function. Same for the virtual unused - could that be a constructor?